# libvirtError that domain already exists, but virsh list doesn't show it

Tags: libvirt, openstack

When I try to launch an instance with OpenStack, I get the following error in nova-compute.log:

```
(nova.rpc): TRACE: libvirtError: operation failed: domain 'instance-0000000a' already exists with uuid 5f81a7d2-1b0f-8c72-4e1e-377c275e9289
```

However, virsh doesn't show any domains:

```
$ sudo virsh list
 Id Name                 State
----------------------------------
```

Why isn't that domain showing up in virsh if it's there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your domain may be shut down. Run `virsh list --all` to see all domains.

Comment: In case `virsh list --all` is empty but the problem persists you may want to try restarting the service `service libvirtd restart`.

Answer (score 4):

Not yet familiar with OpenStack, but in regular old libvirt, that error usually implies not that there's a RUNNING instance, but that there's a DEFINED instance. "virsh list" only shows currently active VM's, not every defined VM. Try:

```
virsh edit instance-0000000a
```

If that pops open vim and has a bunch of XML in there, there's already a defined 'instance-0000000a' VM. If you are 100% sure you don't want it, quit out of the editor and use:

```
virsh undefine instance-0000000a
```

And then have OpenStack try whatever you were doing again, and it should work.

By the way, if you DO want what's there, you can start it with:

```
virsh start instance-0000000a
```

But again, not familiar with OpenStack, it may not like you doing that, no idea.

Comment: I don't know how I forgot "virsh list --all".. thanks to daff for reminding me. Use that instead of "virsh edit" to determine if the domain exists.

Comment: Thanks, 'virsh undefine' is exactly what I needed in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 1:

Are you certain that `virsh` on the command line is talking to the same hypervisor as your OpenStack controller?  This would be the simplest explanation as two why `virsh` is not showing the running instance.

Scenario 2:

If you use `ps`, do you see any `qemu-kvm` instances running?  Try:

```
ps -fe | grep qemu-kvm
```

If there are `qemu-kvm` instances running, they'll have a `-name` parameter that should match the name used in `virsh`.  You can just `kill -9` these processes if they're supposed to be dead anyway.

Comment: Or what @daff said.  That's probably it.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was name resolution. The service *libvirtd* was not starting properly because the hostname wasn't resolving to the system's IP.
Added an entry to */etc/hosts* for local system name and IP, then I could connect to VM guest.

Answer (score 0):

Check if  you have installed
qemu-system-x86-xen
if not - install
apt install qemu-system-x86-xen
that helped me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/500526)